# Can RUI grants be transferred to research universities?

Tags: funding, job, nsf

Suppose a NSF RUI (research at undergraduate institute) proposal is funded. Can the funding be transferred to a research university if the PI move to that university?

Comment: I strongly suggest asking the program director. My experience has been that the NSF is happy with grant modifications as long as the money is spent for the intended research, but my experience does not include RUI grants. There may be rules that require RUI money to be spent only at undergraduate institutions.

Comment: I'll second the recommendation to ask the program director.  Some NSF grants have specific restrictions on which institutions can receive the grants (e.g. EPSCOR grants can only go to EPSCOR states) and you can't violate those restrictions while transferring the grant to another institution (e.g. a PI that I know was not allowed to take her EPSCOR grant to a new job in a non-EPSCOR state.)  I expect that you'd encounter the same problem with trying to transfer an RUI grant to a research university that wouldn't have been eligible for the grant in the first place.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, if your NSF grant is funded as an RUI, then it cannot be moved to another university that is not designated as an PUI.

I wish I had a source on this to link for you, but all I can say is that I was told this last year by an NSF program director regarding pros and cons of applying this way. My understanding is, if you have your grant considered as a RUI, there are a few differences from applying normally:

1. You get to write an "Impact Statement" that does not count against your normal page limit;
2. (at least some of) the reviewers they choose will be from undergraduate serving universities;
3. the reviewers get a "special note" informing them of the circumstances of RUI;
4. there is (maybe?) a special pool of money that can be used to fund some of these (it looks like this is not exactly true, it is not a separate pool; it may vary by program, but sometimes some money is set aside to specifically fund these).

Because you get these special considerations that you would not have at a research university, you (most likely) won't be allowed to transfer this award to a non-You should double check this by emailing your NSF program director to ask.

If you are planning to change to a research university (or try to), you have to consider: If you win an NSF award, it improves your CV and therefore your chances of getting a position, probably regardless of if your award can transfer (though possibly being able to transfer will increase this chance further). So it could be worthwhile to write one considered as an RUI, and just be prepared to leave it behind if you have this opportunity. Or if you feel your application is particularly strong without the extra considerations offered by RUI, you can shoot for the moon and hope for a grant you can take with you.

Comment: For a source, have you looked at the NSF page for RUI grants? https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/pappg19_1/pappg_7.jsp#VIIB2f

Answer (score 2):

Sometimes the funding can be moved. Specifically, both university need to approve the transfer.  The [official program details note:](https://www.nsf.gov/pubs/policydocs/pappg19_1/pappg_7.jsp#VIIB2f)

> (i) Policy. When a PI/PD plans to leave an organization during the course of a grant, the organization has the prerogative to nominate a substitute PI/PD or request that the grant be terminated and closed out. In those cases where the PI/PD's original and new organizations agree, NSF will facilitate a transfer of the grant and the assignment of remaining unobligated funds to the PI/PD's new organization. This should normally be done with a tripartite agreement (involving NSF, the PI/PD’s original organization and new organization), or by a subaward arrangement between the PI/PD's original and new organizations, subject to NSF's consent. (See Chapter VII.B.3)

There are other details on the NSF webpage as well. I would encourage you to read that page if you have an RUI grant and this situation applies to you.